# Producer-Consumer using a stack in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am using a stack as my storage to implement my Producer-Consumer model.

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stackable<Integer> stack = new MyArrayStack<Integer>();
    Producer producer = new Producer(stack);
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer(stack);
    producer.start();
    consumer.start();
}

private static class Producer extends Thread {
    public Producer(Stackable<Integer> s) {
        mStack = s;
    }

    private Stackable<Integer> mStack = null;
    private int mNumber = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO generates number here
        while(true){        synchronized(this){
                while(!mStack.isEmpty())
                {
                    try{
                        this.wait();
                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            mNumber++;
            System.out.println("Producer generates number:" + mNumber);
            mStack.push(mNumber);
            this.notifyAll();
            }
        }   
    }
}

private static class Consumer extends Thread {
    public Consumer(Stackable<Integer> s) {
        mStack = s;
    }

    private Stackable<Integer> mStack = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO consume number here.
        while(true){
            synchronized(this){
                while(mStack.isEmpty())
                {
                    try{
                        this.wait();
                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            int number = mStack.pop();
            System.out.println("Consumer consumes number:" + number);
            this.notifyAll();
            }
        }}

}
```

}

Howver, when I test the program, it seems only the producer will work, it keeps generating numbers while consumer thread seems not be working.

Could expert help me debug where I went wrong in my code? Thanks.

Edit: My code for  my stack is :
    public class MyArrayStack implements Stackable {

```
private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 16;
protected int sp; // empty stack
protected E[] head; // array
private int size;
private int count;

MyArrayStack(int size) {
    if (size <= 0)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                     "Stack's capacity must be positive");
    head = (E[])new Object[size];
    sp = -1;
    count=0;

}






public boolean isFull() {
    return sp == this.size -1;
}

@Override
public void push(Object e) {

    if (!isFull())
    {
        head[++sp] = (E) e;
        count++;
    }

}

@Override
public E pick() {
    if (sp == -1)
        try {
            throw new Exception("Stack is empty");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return head[sp];
}

@Override
public E pop() {
    count--;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else
        return head[sp--];

}

@Override
public int count() {

    return count;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {

    return (sp == -1);
}
}
```

Comment: What happens in the consumer thread's run() method? Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: What do you see when you debug this?  Do you see for example that the two threads are waiting and notifyAll() on unrelated objects?  I suggest you implement a blocking take() and a blocking offer() which block when the stack is full or empty.  Don't trying doing the externally or you are more likely to confuse yourself.

Comment: Yes, it prints nothing.

Comment: What does "yes" mean?  When you ran your program in debug, the debugger screen was completely blank or it just threw lots of numbers at your which made no sense?  The debugger doesn't "print nothing"

Comment: @PeterLawrey, It prints a lot of numbers which don't make any sense to me, they are in the format "Producer generates number:383349" and sth. like that.

Comment: are you getting any exception also. before this line
            System.out.println("Consumer consumes number:" + number);

Comment: How is your pop() method implemented.. Will it give any exception at line nt number = mStack.pop();// Incase stack is empty. Post your code of pop()

Comment: Sorry, no error with pop, Just check my answer with code.

Comment: @Kevin, your code still wait/notifyAll on unrelated objects as I suggested so I assume that is the mostly likely cause of your problem.  You really should learn how to use a debugger as this would solve your problem much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you should `synchronize` and  call `wait()`, `notifyAll()` on `mStack` and not `this`. By using `this` in your `Producer` you are waiting on producer object and in `Consumer` you are waiting on consumer object which is not correct. So you must call `wait()` as well as `notifyAll()` on same object which in your case should be `mStack`.

Here is the code snippet that works fine:

```
package com.thread.concurrency;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main mainObj = new Main();
        List<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Producer producer = mainObj.new Producer(stack);
        Consumer consumer = mainObj.new Consumer(stack);
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }

    private class Producer extends Thread {
        public Producer(List<Integer> s) {
            mStack = s;
        }

        private List<Integer> mStack = null;
        private int mNumber = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO generates number here
            while (true) {
                synchronized (mStack) {
                    while(!mStack.isEmpty())
                    {
                        try{
                            mStack.wait(); // this.wait();
                        } catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                mNumber++;
                System.out.println("Producer generates number:" + mNumber);
                mStack.add(mNumber);
                    mStack.notifyAll();// this.notifyAll();
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    private class Consumer extends Thread {
        public Consumer(List<Integer> s) {
            mStack = s;
        }

        private List<Integer> mStack = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO consume number here.
            while(true){
                synchronized (mStack) {
                    while(mStack.isEmpty())
                    {
                        try{
                            mStack.wait(); // this.wait();
                        } catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                int number = ((LinkedList<Integer>) mStack).removeLast();
                System.out.println("Consumer consumes number:" + number);
                    mStack.notifyAll();// this.notifyAll();
                }
            }}

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it starts processing again. But the result is still buch of "producer producing ....", I still couldn't see consumer thread.

Comment: @Kevin, Did you try my code snippet, it just works fine. Here is the output:Producer generates number:1
Consumer consumes number:1
Producer generates number:2
Consumer consumes number:2
Producer generates number:3
Consumer consumes number:3
........

Comment: your code works perfectly. However, if I change the List back to my Stackable, then it is the same error. Maybe my stack implementation has issues in it?

Comment: yeah, that might be the case. But still you need to `synchronize` on `mStack` and not `this`.

Comment: @KuldeepJain, One question, is it necessary to synchronize the shared resource in the producer? Please clear my confusion.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay, yes it is. as `The current thread must own this object's monitor` for calling `wait()`. Please read about it at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 1):

Oh . I have the issue, you are synchronising on this, instead of that synchronise on stack object, like `synchronized(mStack){`

then wait and notify on this object.

Adding code for you help. I had changed stack to list in my code , because i didnt had your stack object.

```
private static class Producer extends Thread {
    public Producer(List<Integer> s) {
        mStack = s;
    }

    private List<Integer> mStack = null;
    private int mNumber = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO generates number here
        while(true){        synchronized(mStack){
                while(!mStack.isEmpty())
                {
                    try{
                        mStack.wait();
                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            mNumber++;
            System.out.println("Producer generates number:" + mNumber);
            mStack.add(mNumber);
            mStack.notify();
            }
        }   
    }
}

private static class Consumer extends Thread {
    public Consumer(List<Integer> s) {
        mStack = s;
    }

    private List<Integer> mStack = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO consume number here.
        while(true){
            synchronized(mStack){
                while(mStack.isEmpty())
                {
                    try{
                         mStack.wait();
                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            int number = mStack.remove(0);
            System.out.println("Consumer consumes number:" + number);
            mStack.notify();
            }
        }}

}}
```